# Search results are showing full page instead of sample

Tags: search

My search results page is showing full pages instead of just part of a page and I can't figure out how to change it.  I feel like I changed it TO show the full page but I can't remember how I did that and now I want to change it back.

Here is my search.php code.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id='container'>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( smt_translate( 'searchresults' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            /*
             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', 'get_post_format()' ); 

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;

        // Previous/next page navigation.
        get_template_part('navigation');

    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>

    </div>
```

I'm using yoast seo and elementor plugins, so I don't know if that's affecting anything either.  Any tips pointing me in the right direction would be great!  Everything I've read online says to replace the_content with the_excerpt, but all I have are "content" and I tried replacing those but it either did nothing or search results came up blank.

Thanks!

Comment: `get_template_part( 'content', 'get_post_format()' ); ` is the line that's telling it to display the full contents. Instead of calling a template part, try replacing that full line with `the_excerpt();`.

Comment: Doing that shows the excerpt...unfortunatlly that's all it shows.  Nothing is clickable. no title, just the first part of the text.  So...kinda half way there... lol

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: https://smthemes.com/pokemon/  I compared the search.php to the original file with what I have now and it's identical. So I guess I changed something elsewhere. I'm so confused and I've been messing with it for 4 hours now

Comment: Ok, one option then would be to copy your content template part file into a new file (perhaps `search-excerpt`) and just change the call to `the_content()` there to `the_excerpt`. You can then call `get_template_part('search-excerpt')` in `search.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to theme settings in dashboard (Pokemon -> Layout) and set option "**Cut content on the Front/Category page**" to **ON**.

---

#### **Update #1**

To change the way posts are displayed only on the search page, you can add `|| is_search()` after `smt_getOption( 'layout', 'cuttxton' )`

```
if( smt_getOption( 'layout', 'cuttxton' ) || is_search() )
```

But it will be better to save the changed `content.php` file under a new name `content_search.php`:

```
    <?php if ( !is_single() ) : ?>

        <!-- ========== Post content in posts feed ========== -->
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php
                if ( ! post_password_required() ) { 
                    smt_excerpt( 'echo=1' );
                } else the_content( );
            ?>
            <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='button'><?php echo smt_translate( 'readmore' ); ?></a>
            <span class='post-categories'><?php the_category(' '); ?></span> 
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

    <?php endif; ?> 

    <div class="clear"></div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

and in `search.php` use the new template file:

```
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content_search' ); 

// End the loop.
endwhile;
```

#### Excerpt lenght

The excerpt lenght can be changed with `excerpt_length` filter ([doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length)). You can also change length of excerpt in your theme options ("Pokemon" -> "Layout" -> "The default excerpt length").

Code goes to `functions.php`:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;  // number of words
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: That setting is on.  I'm on mobile atm and can't test your code but does that affect the search results page or the main pages?

Comment: Okay so that code work, but I'm just curious, does that change stuff anywhere else other than the search results?  I don't want to run into something random that I'm not aware of.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, this change affects also archive and front page (main page). Do you want show excerpt only on search and full content in other places (main page, archive page)? @Tigerbite

Comment: This is okay unless it's simple to do the excerpt only on search.  Also, where/how can I change how long the excerpt is?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I updated the answer. @Tigerbite

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again for your help!  Got it working the way I wanted and learned a little bit more.  :)

Comment: Good, you are welcome. Please accept answer as correct (["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)) @Tigerbite